# Deleted_by is not changing while i delete a data using observers;

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-9

I want to have fields created_by,updated_by and deleted_by and want to update these fields automatically. created_by,updated_by is working but deleted_by is not working.i am using an observer to perform this task. When i use dd($model) in deleting function in observer it shows the  collection or values but the deleted_by is not updating.

My model

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Observers\UserIdFinderObserver;

class supplier extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'address', 'contact','contact_person_name','country','email'
    ];

   
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        $class = get_called_class();
        $class::observe(new UserIdFinderObserver());
    
      
    }
}
```

my migration file

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('contact_person_name');
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->text('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('contact')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('deleted_by')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My delete function in controller

```
 public function destroy(supplier $supplier)
    {
        try{
            $supplier->delete();
            return redirect()->route('supplier.index')->with('success', 'Supplier is deleted successfully');
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My Observer

```
namespace App\Observers;

class UserIdFinderObserver
{
    private $userID;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->userID = auth()->id();
    }

    public function saving($model)
    {
        $model->created_by = $this->userID;
    }

    


    public function updating($model){
            $model->updated_by = $this->userID;
    }

   


    public function creating($model)
    {
        $model->created_by = $this->userID;
    }

    


   
    public function deleting($model)
    {
        $model->deleted_by = $this->userID;
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: Did you Register Observers class on provider??

Comment: creating and updating is working except deleting

Comment: @IrfanMajid The deleting observer not work when using softdelete functionality. You can find more about it here https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18119